# Can places be used without に?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

When studying the famous song 君がくれたもの, I came across the following line:

ああ、花火が夜空綺麗に咲いて......

While trying to understand this line grammatically, I realize although it means “fireworks bloomed beautifully in the night sky,” the 夜空 is not used with に to mark a place. The に in the sentence is paired with 綺麗 to make 綺麗 and adverb(so it doesn’t go with 夜空). When I look up 夜空, almost all examples use 夜空に to say “in the night sky”. So, given this could not possibly be a mistake, is there a grammatical point I don’t understand or is the に left out for lyrical purposes?

Comment: i’m a nonnative speaker: so i’ll hold off on making this an answeer. but it seems to me that  the particle is dropped for the purposes of meter.  if you listen to the song, the lyrics are very clearly following a definite metrical rhythm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually used with "に". This is a song and cutting it off for some reason.

It feels like an `体言止め` to me.

But it's not the end of a sentence, so it may not be exactly `体言止め`.

We learn about `体言止め` in Japan around junior high school. `体言止め` is a common technique used in haiku（俳句）.

`体言止め` is to end a sentence with a noun.

Let me quote something that sounds like it.

- [体言止めを使ってみよう！ | わかば国語・作文教室](https://ameblo.jp/wakaba-sakubun/entry-11577525465.html)

> 【体言止めの例題】
>
> 問：次の文を体言止めにしてみましょう。
>
> あのとき見た空の青さを、僕は忘れない。
>
> （この文の中の名詞は３つ。
> 　「空」「青さ」「僕」）
> ↓
>
> ○A:あのとき見た空。その青さを、僕は忘れない。
>
> ○B:あのとき見た空の青さ。それを僕は忘れない。
>
> ×C:あのとき見た空の青さを、僕。その人は忘れない。

In Japanese, ○ means OK and × means no.

The effect of `体言止め` is `余韻を残すこと`.
In English, I don't know what to say.

another sample:

- [文法スイスイ！ 「体言止め」が一瞬で分かる！ | 中学生の「国語」のコツ](https://www.all5.jp/subject/246.html)

> ［“体言止め” の例］
>
> ・これが、父がくれた自転車。
>
> ・まあ、なんて素晴らしい青空。
>
> ・宿の自慢は、窓から見える美しい海岸。